# Why is JavaScript not entering a For...in loop

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

For some reason, the below for...in loop does not execute when I step through line by line. It looks like it reads the Object, and the 'let outerLoopProp' statement and then skips over the entire body of the loop.

The loop sits within a Form submit event.

I have logged the Object to the console and it is populated with properties by time the code reaches the for..in loop.

```js
form1.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let forValidationCheck = {};
  let allNames = ["Tarp 1", "Tarp 2", "Tarp 3"];

  for(let r = 0; r < allNames.length; r++) {
                    
    let currentChosen = allNames[r].toLowerCase();
    let optionsForCheck = document.getElementById(`selection${r+1}`);
    let selectedArrayForCheck = [];
                    
    for(z=0; z < optionsForCheck.options.length; z++) {
      if(optionsForCheck.options[z].selected === true) {
          selectedArrayForCheck.push(optionsForCheck.options[z].value.toLowerCase());
      }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(forValidationCheck, currentChosen, {
        value: selectedArrayForCheck
    })
  }

  for(let layerOuterLoop in forValidationCheck) {
      //Code within for..in loop
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <select name="selection1" id="selection1">
    <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
    <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selection2" id="selection2" >
    <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
    <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selection3" id="selection3">
    <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
    <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to be runnable on-site, as you can see, the issue you described does not occur. Your problem must lie elsewhere. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @MisterJojo `e.preventDefault()` prevents that.

Comment: I've undone my and @nit's  edits since they erased the problem. The problem is that you're missing the `)` at the end of the function.

Comment: The code, as you posted it, has syntax errors. You should be seeing those in your browser's console.

Comment: @Barmar That sounds more like a copy-paste error given the question states he was able to step through it with a debugger.

Comment: @Nit Good point. Could the OP please paste the code correctly so we can have a better chance to answer?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the edits.. first post. I do see any syntax errors. The above is a bit more simple as a for loop, which loops through an array is used to populate the Program Check object. Not sure if that may be contributing to the issue, but I have logged the Program Check object to the console after that loop runs and it was working correctly.

Comment: I will work on a minimum reproducible example now.

Comment: I have added a minimum reproducible example, I am having trouble getting the HTML to show seperately as @barmar updated so that it can be run in site. If anyone could assist would be great and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: **optionsForCheck** is null  **forValidationCheck** is Empty

Comment: @MisterJojo it gets populated by the for loop, using the Object.defineProperty() method. I have logged forValidationCheck to the console and it is populated before we get to the for..in loop which is supposed to loop through it.

Comment: It is now runnable in site.

Comment: @MisterJojo you're right, I have added a Selection 3, but the larger issue of the for in loop not running is still there.

Comment: This because you use Object.defineProperty => writable is false  see  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @MisterJojo the Mozilla reference put me on the right track, I is the 'enumerable' property that needs to be set to true when using the Object.defineProperty() method if you want to loop through the resultant object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have posted a better and shorter solution, did you see it ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: When using Object.defineProperty(), you need to set enumerable: true for the third argument of the method. See below. Thanks all for the help!

```js
form1.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

 let forValidationCheck = {};
 let allNames = ["Tarp 1", "Tarp 2", "Tarp 3"];

   for(let r = 0; r < allNames.length; r++) {
                    
                    let currentChosen = allNames[r].toLowerCase();
                    let optionsForCheck = document.getElementById(`selection${r+1}`);
                    let selectedArrayForCheck = [];
                    
                    for(z=0; z < optionsForCheck.options.length; z++) {
                        if(optionsForCheck.options[z].selected === true) {
                            selectedArrayForCheck.push(optionsForCheck.options[z].value.toLowerCase());
                        }
                    }
                    Object.defineProperty(forValidationCheck, currentChosen, {
                        value: selectedArrayForCheck,
                        enumerable: true
                    })
                }


                for(let layerOuterLoop in forValidationCheck) {

                   //Code within for..in loop

                }

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form id="form1">

 <select name="selection1" id="selection1">
  <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
  <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
 </select>

 <select name="selection2" id="selection2">
  <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
  <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
 </select>

 <select name="selection3" id="selection3">
  <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
  <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
 </select>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in this case using **Object.defineProperty** is not appropriate

Answer (score 0):

there is a more simpler for doing the same thing :

```js
const myForm   = document.getElementById('form1')
    , allNames ={ 'Tarp 1': myForm.selection1
                , 'Tarp 2': myForm.selection2
                , 'Tarp 3': myForm.selection3
                }

myForm.onsubmit=e=>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let forValidationCheck = {}

  for (let aN in allNames)
    {
    forValidationCheck[aN.toLowerCase()] = allNames[aN].value
    //forValidationCheck[aN.toLowerCase()] = [allNames[aN].value] //if prefered 
    }

  for (let layerOuterLoop in forValidationCheck)
    {
    console.log(layerOuterLoop, ' => ',forValidationCheck[layerOuterLoop] )
    }
  }

/* -- in case of selects are multiple : -...
  for (let aN in allNames)
    {
    forValidationCheck[aN.toLowerCase()] = [...allNames[aN].options]
                                              .filter(option=>option.selected)
                                              .map(option=>option.value)
    }
*/
```

```html
<form id="form1">

  <select name="selection1">
    <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
    <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selection2">
    <option value="Tarp 2">Tarp 2</option>
    <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
  </select>

  <select name="selection3">
    <option value="Tarp 1">Tarp 1</option>
    <option value="Tarp 3">Tarp 3</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```